# CSS Grid hover is "shuffeling"

Tags: css, hover, css-grid

So I'm working on my portfolio page with a grid section. The problem is, when I hover above one item, it sort of randomly triggers other hover animations from that grid

the code used for the grid is following

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>

.content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  margin: 0 10%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

::selection {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  margin: 0 10%;
  width: 80%;
}

.item {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 22px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  transition: box-shadow 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1), transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1), background 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  height: 99%;
}

.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 22px 2px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}

.item .dimmer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: rgba(18, 18, 18, 0);
  transition: background .2s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item:hover .dimmer {
  background: rgba(18, 18, 18, .5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item .description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 35%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item:hover .description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 35%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item .description h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transform: translateY(50px);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1), color 1s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.item:hover .description h2 {
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.item .description p {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transform: translateY(50px);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1), color 1s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.item:hover .description p {
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0.275s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="head">
  <h1>Eric Wätke</h1>
  <a href="#">Über Mich</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="dimmer"></div>
    <video autoplay loop width="100%">
       <source src="https://i.imgur.com/QPMfiUH.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Technica Light & Sound</h2>
      <p>Event company</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="dimmer"></div>
    <video autoplay loop width="100%">
          <source src="https://i.imgur.com/QPMfiUH.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Technica Light & Sound</h2>
      <p>Event company</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="dimmer"></div>
    <video autoplay loop width="100%">
          <source src="https://i.imgur.com/QPMfiUH.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Technica Light & Sound</h2>
      <p>Event company</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/cire901/project/full/XabEpV/

Comment: `position:absolute`, in your `.item .description` is what messing with your hover. Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `.item` divs you have content that is set to `position: absolute`, presumably as you intend them to be sized and place in relation to `.item`.

When you hover over it looks like this is working fine, but if you remove `transform: translateY(-20px);` from `.item:hover` you will see that the `.description` and `.dimmer` content gets positioned relative to the `<html>` element.

This is because you haven't defined a 'positioning context' on the `.item`. Whenever you position something 'absolutely', it is based on a 'position context'. By default it will be the `<html>` element - so if you set an element to `position: absolute; top: 50%;' it would be positioned 50% from the top of the`` element, not its direct parent.

You can change this by setting a 'position context'. There are a number of ways to do it, but the most common is to set `position: relative` on the item you want it to be contextually set by. So in your case you would want to add it to `.item`.

The reason it looks like it is working when you hover over it is that setting a `transform` property on an element also triggers the position context, and you have this:

```
.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 22px 2px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

This means when you hover over the `.item` its content is positioned in relation to `.item`, but as you move away it becomes positioned in relation to `html`. This causes it to switch position rapidly, and your cursor will sometimes move between hovering and not hovering many times per second as it flicks around - because whenever you are hovering over a child of `.item` you are triggering the `.item` hover even if it doesn't look like you are hovering over `.item` itself.
The simplest solution for you would be to add `position: relative` to your `.item` selector.

Because you are transforming the position of `.item` you will still get a judder if you hover at the very bottom of the `.item`. This is because as the item moves up the screen (because of `transform: translateY(-20px)` on hover) it moves the hover position with it. As it moves up you are not hovering over it any more, so it begins to move back down. To prevent this you can add an invisible pseudo-element on hover that occupies the space it moves:

```
.item{
  &:before{
  content:'';
  display: block;
  top:100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
.item:hover::before{
  height: 20px;
}
```

You could transition that too to match the movement speed, but it's probably not necessary.

To take things one step further, because you are already using CSS Grid you could remove your absolute positioning entirely. You could add this to `.item`:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr;
align-content: stretch;
justify-content: stretch;
```

This sets it as a grid with only one column and one row and stretches the content to fill it.

You then add this to tell all direct descendants to fill that one column and row, rather than forming new implicit rows:

```
.item>*{
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

And finally you would set your `.description` to `align-self: center;` thus positioning itself vertically centered.

You can see an example of all of this here: https://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/qopdNp

I've colored the pseudo-element red so you can see the example - you would want to remove that. I've commented out the code of yours that I deleted and have noted where I've added a line. I also switched your videos to jpegs for now as I was having issues with them loading. That shouldn't have any effect on the CSS though.